# Convert a file with variable-length records to fixed-length records in Java

Tags: java, cobol

I have a requirement where I need to convert a file containing variable-length records into fixed-length records. This is a file from a Mainframe.

Since I don't access to files on the Mainframe, I need a sample variable-length record file and a way to convert to fixed-length records.

I am totally new to this kind of file. But if I get an idea to of how to map these variable-length records to fixed-length I can code it in Java.

This is my variable length file:

```
1 piyush    pankaj    04mathematic10physics   20biology   45   
2 vanitha   reddy     03physics   30chemistry 60   
3 deepesh   shetty    05chemistry 5 biology   45
4 jane      dsouja    01geography 30chemistry 60biology   45
5 ramadasa  hegde     02chemistry 80biology   70
```

This is how my how my fields are positioned:

```
05  ID                         PIC 99.  
05  FNAME                      PIC X(10).   
05  LNAME                      PIC X(10).
05  NO_SUB                     PIC X(2).
05  SUBJECTS OCCURS 0 TO 10 TIMES
          DEPENDING ON NO_SUB
       10  SUB_NAME            PIC X(10).
       10  MARKS               PIC 99.
```

So i am expecting an output like this :

```
1 piyush    pankaj    04mathematic10
1 piyush    pankaj    04physics   20
1 piyush    pankaj    04biology   70
2 vanitha   reddy     03physics   30
2 vanitha   reddy     03chemistry 60
3 deepesh   shetty    05chemistry  5 
3 deepesh   shetty    05biology   45
4 jane      dsouja    01geography 30
4 jane      dsouja    01chemistry 60
4 jane      dsouja    01biology   70
5 ramadasa  hegde     02chemistry 80
5 ramadasa  hegde     02biology   70
```

Comment: And how do you determine the target length? What if the file is longer? What is the rest of the file supposed to be filled with if the file is shorter?

Comment: @fge I dont have any sample file for variable length file .

Comment: and how is the variable-length file organized? Is it a mainframe-file with a 4-byte-length-field preceding each record or is it CRLF-separated?

Comment: That is not what I was asking; basically I was asking about the process you need to follow to convert those variable-length files into fixed-length files and what should happen in corner case situations. You don't describe any of these in your question

Comment: @piet.t Can i have sample files for both ?

Comment: On the mainframe you use sort to translate VB to FB. Which Cobol are we talking about ???. Is your java program running under zOS or some other operating system.

Comment: This question is unanswerable. You need a sample of the *actual* file, and a specification of both its format and the desired output format. It would make a lot more sense to me for someone to program this in COBOL rather than Java, but whatever the case, nobody could do it with as little information as you've presented here.

Comment: I am working on getting the sample file . Once I get it . I will tell the detail .

Comment: I have added a sample file

Comment: And there is nothing variable about what you have shown. How/why did Vanitha's physics get moved? Neither of your two PIC 99 fields are correct, as you show left-justified space-padded data in them. You should write 36 bytes of your input data, then 24 bytes and concatenate the final 12. How is that difficult?

Comment: @BillWoodger Sorry for the confusion . I have edited the question once again

Answer (score 4):

On the **mainframe** you can use the **sort** utility to convert from VB to FB. See [using sort to copy from VB to FB](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.iceg200/ice1cg4044.htm). While you are at it, sort can also convert binary fields to text fields.

If the Java is running on zOS you should be able to use IBM's supplied classes to read VB files (see [JZOS Java Launcher and Toolkit](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/tools/java/products/jzos/overview.html). What platform are you running the java on ???

As a **last resort** it is possible to read VB files, the format is not difficult, I can supply code for reading VB files(the difficult bit is transporting the VB file to another platform).

---

Finally can you **clarify** the question, for example what platform is the java running, how are you reading / transferring the files, are the files binary files ???.

I suspect there is actually no need to do a VB to FB conversion because

- If running java on zOS there are IBM supplied classes that will read VB files.
- If you are transporting the files to another platform:

  - You can convert any binary field to text fields using the sort utility
  - Do a Text File transfer (with EBCIDIC to ASCII translation). For text transfers it should not matter wether it is a FB or VB file.

The only time VB files should be an issue is for Binary VB files

Comment: I have added a sample file

Answer (score 3):

This is your record-layout in COBOL:

```
05  ID                         PIC 99.  
05  FNAME                      PIC X(10).   
05  LNAME                      PIC X(10).
05  NO_SUB                     PIC X(2).
05  SUBJECTS OCCURS 0 TO 10 TIMES
          DEPENDING ON NO_SUB
       10  SUB_NAME            PIC X(10).
       10  MARKS               PIC 99.
```

This is not valid.

Firstly, ID is a Reserved Word, it is a shortening of IDENTIFICATION.

Secondly, NO_SUB is mentioned in `OCCURS ... DEPENDING ON ...` so must be numeric (in this case a PIC 99).

Thirdly, there is a full-stop/period missing after NO_SUB in the ODO.

Fourthly, from what you have shown of the data, ID and MARKS are both defined incorrectly. ID (when it has a proper name) should be PIC XX and MARKS either PIC XX or perhaps PIC Z9.

Your data is entirely textual, so there is no problem at all in transferring it from the Mainframe by preferred method and allowing the transfer to do the EBCDIC to ASCII translation, and delimit your records with whatever is appropriate for your file-system.

You will then have some variable-length records on your system.

The key to being able to understand them is the value in NO_SUB for each individual record.

Each record has a fixed length of 24 bytes (the fields from ID to NO_SUB inclusive).

Records with a NO-SUB of `00` have no data beyond that point, you should just see your record delimiter.

Otherwise, NO_SUB should contain a numeric value of 01-10 inclusive, which will represent the length of the variable part of your data in this way: variable-length = NO_SUB * 12. The 12 is the length of SUB_NAME plus the length of MARKS.

To output the data you require, you need the fixed part of the record, plus the appropriate variable part (if there is one, don't forget the zero in NO_SUB, and you'll need to find out what, if anything, to output for that) accessed in some way in some type of looping construct.

Having said all that, there is only one example in your data which is correct, the final record.

If NO_SUB is 03, you should find three blocks of (10-bytes-text, 2-bytes-numeric). If NO_SUB is 05, you should find five similar blocks.

With your final record, you should output:

```
Byte 1 for a length of 24 + Byte 25 for a length of 12
Byte 1 for a length of 24 + Byte 37 for a length of 12
```

The variable part of your record starts at byte 25 and is 12 long. You output the first variable part from byte 25, the second from 37, the third from 49 etc.

Start-position-to-output is `( 25 + ( 12 * ( occurrence-in-loop - 1 ) ) )`, where 25 is the position of the first variable part of your data, and 12 is the length of each individual element of your variable data.

Giving you:

```
5 ramadasa  hegde     02chemistry 80
5 ramadasa  hegde     02biology   70
```

You should check that NO_SUB is numeric, and that it is not greater than 10, and find out what you should do it either of those is not the case.

in Java you can use the **substr** method to extract the fields e.g.

```
String id = inputLine.substr(1,2);
String firstName = inputLine.substr(3,12);
String lastName  = inputLine.substr(13,22);
String numberOfEntriesStr = inputLine.substr(23,24);

int numberOfEntries = Integer.parseInt(numberOfEntriesStr);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries) {
   ...
}
```

There are fixed width java packages + some that can read files using a Cobol copybook but they would be a complete over kill for this.